# Duplicate Rows After Query Modification

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

Original Query returns 259 rows. After modifying, query returns 271 rows. These twelve rows are duplicates. How can I avoid this? Thanks for your help!!

**Query (modifications bold):**

```
select "Item", "Expires", "Lot #", "Subinv", "Locator", "Qty", "UOM", "Lead Time"
,(select count(*) from MTL_KANBAN_CARDS_V kb where exp.inventory_item_id = kb.inventory_item_id and kb.card_status_name <> 'Hold') "Kanban Cards (Not On Hold)"
FROM (
SELECT msi.inventory_item_id
,msi.segment1                             "Item"
,mln.expiration_date                      "Expires"
,mln.lot_number                           "Lot #"
,moqd.subinventory_code                   "Subinv"
,mil.segment1                             "Locator"
,sum(moqd.primary_transaction_quantity)   "Qty"
,msi.primary_uom_code                     "UOM"
**,muc.conversion_rate                      "UOM Conversion Rate"**
,msi.FULL_LEAD_TIME                       "Lead Time"

FROM mtl_system_items_b msi 
,mtl_onhand_quantities_detail moqd
,mtl_lot_numbers mln
,mtl_item_locations mil
**,mtl_uom_conversions muc**

WHERE msi.organization_id = 101
AND moqd.inventory_item_id = msi.inventory_item_id
AND moqd.organization_id = msi.organization_id 
**AND muc.inventory_item_id (+) = msi.inventory_item_id**
AND mln.inventory_item_id  = msi.inventory_item_id
AND mln.organization_id = msi.organization_id
AND mln.lot_number = moqd.lot_number
AND mln.expiration_date <= SYSDATE+365
AND mil.organization_id(+) = moqd.organization_id
AND mil.inventory_location_id(+) = moqd.locator_id

GROUP BY msi.inventory_item_id
,msi.segment1
,mln.expiration_date
,mln.lot_number
,moqd.subinventory_code
,mil.segment1 
,msi.primary_uom_code
**,muc.conversion_rate**
,msi.FULL_LEAD_TIME

ORDER BY msi.segment1
,mln.expiration_date
,mln.lot_number) exp
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that mtl_uom_conversions does not contain any duplicate inventory_item_id?

Comment: I do not believe this is guaranteed. I am not in IT, so can't be sure.

Comment: They are exact duplicates, even of the `conversion_rate` value? If not which would you want to keep? (Also, you should consider using modern outer join syntax, rather than Oracle's old syntax. The subquery in the select list looks odd too, can't that be another join?).

Comment: try "select count(*) from mtl_uom_conversions group by inventory_item_id having count(*) > 1" to check for any duplicates;

Comment: Alex Poole - Yes, they are exact duplicates. Not sure what you mean by which I'd want to keep?

Comment: When modifying the query, do you also include `"UOM Conversion Rate"`to the select list in the very outer select statement? If not, please try. I'd expect different conversion rate values then for the "duplicates".

Comment: Stephan Lechner - Great catch, but this didn't fix the issue.

Comment: No - it does not fix the issue, but it indicates that there a duplicate entries for the same id in mtl_oum_conversions... And if this is true, then this will help solving the problem in the next step. Please try `select count(*) from mtl_uom_conversions group by inventory_item_id having count(*) > 1`; If there are no duplicates, then the query returns no result; But I expect to get about 12 lines...

Comment: Stephan - I got 13 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to formulate it as an answer:

For 13 items, there are more than one `conversion_rate` values for a particular `inventory_item_id`, and that's why these additional rows shine up once you extend the query by `mtl_uom_conversions`;

If you do not want to have them all, you could either...

(1) remove these duplicates; I think this is OK, because for me it seems as if the data in the DB were inconsistent / redundant in this case

(2) remove `muc.conversion_rate` from the group by clause and add `min(muc.conversion_rate)` in the (inner) select clause; you could use also MAX, or whatever, but if you have more values, but want just one, you have to decide which one :-)

Comment: Thank you, Stephen!

Comment: Tried to upvote your answer, but I'm locked out due to low reputation. Wish I could give you gold a la reddit.

Comment: Maybe you can accept the answer; Actually I do not know how :-)